# Dark mode - how to handle the auto preference

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

In this darkmode code I allow the user to set the `theme` through `system preferences` while also allowing the user to override the system preferred theme by toggling the `button` or `radio`.

How do I set `checked` state for the `system default` radio when the user changes their system preference to `auto`?

Since it changes `prefers-color-scheme` to either light or dark how would I detect the user changing their preference to `auto` in order to update the radio's `checked` state? I tried adding the `checked` state inside of `if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)").matches) {}` but it didn't execute.

Also I can't figure out why my `window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {}` isn't detecting the user selected theme on load. It's defaulting to `light` even when the page is refreshed and the theme in settings is set to dark.

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/VwmaPMV

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setLight() {
    $("body").removeClass("dark-theme");
    $("body").addClass("light-theme");
    $("#light").prop("checked", true);
    $('input[name="theme"]').change();
  }

  function setDark() {
    $("body").addClass("dark-theme");
    $("body").removeClass("light-theme");
    $("#dark").prop("checked", true);
    $('input[name="theme"]').change();
  }

  function setMode() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
      $("#dark").prop("checked", true);
      $('input[name="theme"]').change();
      setDark();
    } else {
      $("#light").prop("checked", true);
      $('input[name="theme"]').change();
      setLight();
    }
  }
  //Check the mode on load and style accordingly
  if (localStorage.getItem("mode") == "dark-theme") {
    setDark();
  } else {
    setLight();
  }
  //Check for when system default is changed -> change theme
  window
    .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
    .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("mode") !== null) {
        //Manually set so don't do anything
      } else {
        setMode();
      }
    });
  window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    //If the mode is mannually set on load - choose that mode
    if (localStorage.getItem("mode") !== null) {
      // Do nothing the mode has been set manually
    } else {
      // Set the mode to the default
      setMode();
    }
  });
  //add toggle
  $("#toggleTheme").on("click", function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("dark-theme")) {
      localStorage.setItem("mode", "light-theme");
      setLight();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark-theme");
      setDark();
    }
  });
  $("#light").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "light-theme");
    setLight();
  });
  $("#dark").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark-theme");
    setDark();
  });
  $("#default").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("mode");
    if (localStorage.getItem("mode") !== null) {
      setMode();
    }
  });
});

//For selecting radio
$('input[name="theme"]').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("label.checked").removeClass("checked");
    $(this).closest("label").addClass("checked");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  --font-color: blue;
  --bg-color: white;
  --bg-span: #ececec;
}

body.dark-theme {
  --font-color: white;
  --bg-color: black;
  --bg-span: white;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    --font-color: white;
    --bg-color: black;
    --bg-span: white;
  }
  body.light-theme {
    --font-color: blue;
    --bg-color: white;
    --bg-span: #ececec;
  }
}

body {
  color: var(--font-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

button {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.9rem;
  outline: none;
  color: var(--font-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

span {
  padding: 0.9rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  background: var(--bg-span);
}

img {
  max-width: 190px;
}


/*input {
  display: none;
}*/

label {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

label.checked {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.theme {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons,
.theme {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="toggleTheme">Mode</button>
</div>

<div class="theme">
  <label for="light">
    <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/settings/color_mode_light.svg">
    <input type="radio" name="theme" id="light">
    <span>Light</span>
  </label>
  <label for="dark">
    <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/settings/color_mode_dark.svg">
    <input type="radio" name="theme" id="dark">
    <span>Dark</span>
  </label>
  <label for="default">
    <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/settings/color_mode_auto.svg">
    <input type="radio" name="theme" id="default">
    <span>System Default</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The codepen works just fine for me

Comment: Clear localStorage and switch your system settings to auto and you will see that the checked radio goes to "light" because the system detected light theme however I need the "default "radio to be checked when the system theme is set to auto. Also set your system to dark mode and clear localStorage and you will see that it doesn't load to dark mode when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature `no-preference` of the `prefers-color-scheme` `@media` rule [is deprecated](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_prefers-color-scheme_no-preference) and that's why it does not work any more on latest browsers.

The `load` window event does execute but it doesn't have the appropriate logic in your code. Your code does nothing if the `mode` local storage setting is not `null`, which of course is the case after selecting something.

You should have the following behaviours regarding `mode` setting:

1. `light` for light scheme that will override system/browser setting
2. `dark` for dark scheme that will override system/browser setting
3. Anything elese other than `dark`/`light`, including `null`/`undefined`, will apply what browser setting has, which it can have its own override or reading the OS setting

Also, `setLight`/`setDark` procedures should just apply the theme and not alter any input elements state because it will end up with circular value setting bugs:

```js
function setLight() {
  $("body").removeClass("dark-theme");
  $("body").addClass("light-theme");
}

function setDark() {
  $("body").addClass("dark-theme");
  $("body").removeClass("light-theme");
}
```

Instead, you can have all the inputs change logic inside `setMode` which should check `mode` setting and handle all logic like this:

```js
function setMode() {
  // have a variable to indicate what mode
  // we should apply at the end of the procedure
  let lightMode;

  // always unregister media listener,
  // because we only need it if mode is not set,
  // which then we'll have to read media queries using matchMedia
  unregisterMediaListener();

  switch (localStorage.getItem("mode")) {
    case 'light-theme': {
      lightMode = true;
      $("#light").prop("checked", true);
      break;
    }
    case 'dark-theme': {
      lightMode = false;
      $("#dark").prop("checked", true);
      break;
    }
    default: { // using system setting
      $("#default").prop("checked", true);
      // set lightMode indicator using the matchMedia query result
      lightMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").matches;
      // and register media change listener for changes
      registerMediaListener();
    }
  }

  // allpy new input values
  $('input[name="theme"]').change();

  // set the actual mode
  if (lightMode) {
    setLight();
  } else {
    setDark();
  }
}
```

And finally the `matchMedia` `prefers-color-scheme: light` change listener:

```js
// we set a mediaMatch variable so we can use it and unregister the listener
let mm;

function registerMediaListener() {
  mm = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)");
  mm.addEventListener('change', onLightSchemeChange);
}

function unregisterMediaListener() {
  if (mm) mm.removeListener(onLightSchemeChange);
}

function onLightSchemeChange(scheme) {
  if (scheme.matches) {
    // We have browser/system light scheme
    setLight();
  } else {
    setDark();
  }
}
```

### Working example

You can check this forked and modified pen that is actually working and does select the appropriate setting/option when the page loads: https://codepen.io/clytras/pen/MWberor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I noticed the checked state of the input doesn't change to match when the user changes the theme at the system level.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill you can easily make that work, but why do you need that? If the user chooses to have a `dark`/`light` theme, then that **should not** change when the system changes, because that is the purpose of it, to override the system setting. If the user have the `default` setting selected, then the scheme will change when system setting change. Just think about it; there is no point doing that if I choose a setting other than `default` to be changed automatically when the system changes.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve something similar to github. The checked state just shows the user what their current setting is whether it was set by the system or by them through overriding at site level

Comment: My example works exactly like GitHud does, did you try it? Have your system setting to dark; then set the page to `default` setting; reload the page and it will select the `default` option and apply the dark theme; if you change the system setting to light, then the page will trigger a light media query change and disply in the light theme; but if you have selected `light` or `dark`, the page won't do anything on a system mode change and that is exactly how GitHub works.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're welcome. You should take some time and read my inline comments to figure out and understand how the code works. The logic is quite simple and you were very close having a behaviour like how GitHub works.